# Connect to remote via ssh and run git commands with expect

Tags: bash, ssh, remote-access, git-bash

I'm writing "fake deployment" bash script I want to run to pull latest master on server. I have a following script:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn ssh -t user@host.domain 'cd path/to/dir'
expect "continue"
sleep 1
send "yes\r"
expect "assword:"
sleep 1
send "password\r"

# Commands for remote
git pull origin master
expect "sername"
sleep 1
send "username\r"
expect "assword"
sleep 1
send "password\r"
interact
```

Connection is made successfully, however, when the `git pull origin master` is ran, the error is triggered: `invalid command name "git"`.

I'm probably should run the commands differently, unfortunately, I'm not sure how. How will I be able to run the "Commands for remote" on remote? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: is git installed on the machine? this error mean it doesn't....

Comment: Thanks for comment. Git is surely installed there, as when I do it manually I'm fully able to use git commands. I guess the problem might be that after a connection is established commands are ran in some weird environment (not inside the terminal directly). But I'm writing the bash script for the third time in my life so I'm not sure.

Comment: Regardless of your issue with the git command itself, why are you using **expect**? You can use either  ssh keys : https://help.github.com/articles/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/ or personal access tokens : https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line/ and you avoid having to use expect at all.

Answer (score 0):

`ssh` will leave you on the remote host side with a standard limited `PATH`.

If `git` is not installed in `/usr/bin`, you might have to modify your script in order to write the full path of the `git` executable.

Comment: `which git` outputs that it is installed in `/usr/bin`. I guess there might be some other issue. The weird thing is the message `invalid command name`. Normally, when you try to execute the command which doesn't exist it says `-bash: "command" : command not found`

Comment: @DawidZbiński `which git` when done after the  `exec \$SHEL`?

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't update the code. Here it is, the updated version. I tried running `which git` after manually logging in. It gives the right path `/usr/bin/git/`. I'm still wondering why is the error message that weird. Should probably respond with `command not found` if the command is not found, but it responds with `invalid command name`.

Comment: I added `which git` right before the `git pull origin master` command. It response with `invalid command name 'which'` as well.

Comment: @DawidZbiński Is this similar to https://stackoverflow.com/q/16212628/6309? And https://askubuntu.com/a/959662/5470.

Comment: It's similar to the first one, but it does not give me an error because of "what" I'm expecting. it just doesn't want to run the commands once logged in. Also, I'm wondering... until know I though that the only requirement for me to use expect is to have it installed on my computer (from which I run the script), but doesn't it need to be installed on the remote host too?

Comment: @DawidZbiński you run the script on the remote side though, through ssh.

Comment: I have no clue how does the expect work exactly, but I thought that it's using some sort of listener to wait until terminal wants some data and then sends the response. E.g. in my example, I thought the ssh session will be opened, `git pull origin master` will be ran as an ordinary command, the `expect "sername"` would wait until terminal asks for username, etc. To simplify... I thought expect is just an "extension" in my terminal to input the data when terminal asks for them. So I guess I have it all wrong then, right?

Comment: @DawidZbiński Yes, that seems off, especially when I compare it to https://stackoverflow.com/q/16212628/6309.